# How to disable "Failed to update" sticky notification for Chrome on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, google-chrome, updates

As you've probably all heard, Google is finally ending support for Chrome for Windows 7 - makes sense, with the slow phasing out of the system.

As for now however, I'm still fine using it with the current version, even if it's not updated.

But since recently, everytime I open Chrome on my Asus with Win 7, I get this annoying notification bar on top of the screen saying "To get future updates of Chrome, you need Windows 10 or 11, and you're using Windows 7" (I'm translating back from French). (see sc)

Note that I'm not trying to update, it does that automatically no matter what. (It does it only on first open, not on new tabs). Then I need to manually dimiss the bar every time by clicking on it, which is obviously super annoying and a total waste of time.

Is there any way, or "hack", to permanently remove this?

I tried disabling google auto update in ms.config and services, but to no effect.

On some old forum threads I saw mentions of some Flags that would do something similar, but it doesn't seem to be still active.

I also tried masking it with AdBlock with the feature 'Hide element on this page', but this notification window is not registered (it's like it's a separate element from the rest of the page).

Thanks for the help and the suggestions!

Vincent

Asus N56, Windows 7 64bit, Chrome 108

[image]

Comment: Just close it (1 second).  I have Chrome and Chromium Edge on my Windows 7 VM and both updated to the newest version without issue. Keep it up to date and close the notification (1 second). Chrome is not failing to update.

Comment: @John: not on my system. Closing does nothing, and the notification window comes back anew every time. Obviously - it if was just about "closing the program", I wouldn't have taken the time to write this post. In Chrome parameters ("About") it says the same thing, that it can't be updated any longer on Windows 7 and that it requires Windows 10 or above. It started 1 or 2 days ago, and AFAIK I haven't changed anything on my system.

Comment: As mentioned in the initial post, my issue is not updating Chrome since it won't be supported for Windows 7 anyway. It's removing the annoying notification window (cf screenshot in my first post)

Comment: The one method that did exist, was removed, because it was being abused by malicious software. So based on my research it's currently not possible. You likely have to disable service responsible for checking if Google is updated to prevent the infobar from appearing.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks for your comment and suggestion. I tried to stop google auto-update, to no avail, but maybe I didn't it do it "thoroughly" enough, so I will try again.

Comment: SOLVED. For those having the same issue, here's a video explaining 2 methods to do it (edit registry with "SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning" and run Chrome in test mode): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6OxOZ7KPa4 Big credit and thanks to @noirhor above who initially found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution on reddit

All you have to do is apply the **SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning** policy rule

For current user:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Or system wide:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

[more details about this policy rule](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning)

Comment: thanks so much! That's exactly it. "SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning". I had looked around but hadn't found that specific topic. I will try it.

Comment: Solved. For those having the same issue, here's a video explaining 2 methods to do it (edit registry with "SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning" and run Chrome in test mode):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6OxOZ7KPa4

Big credit and thanks to @noirhor above who initially found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. See my comment to @noirhor for more details. (I tried to post it as an Answer but it was deleted by some random bot).

Big credit and thanks to @noirhor who initially found the solution.

Comment: This too will get deleted by a bot. ease edit it and provide at keast the summary here ans a link or reference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).